# Bias Variance Decomposition for Mean Absolute Error

Tags: variance, bias, mse

The mean squared error of an estimator $\hat{\theta}$ with respect
to an unknown parameter $\theta$ is defined as 
$$
MSE(\hat{\theta})=E[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^{2}].
$$
 It is well known that there is the following bias-variance decomposition:

$$
MSE(\hat{\theta})=Var(\hat{\theta})+\left(Bias(\hat{\theta},\theta)\right)^{2}.
$$
 **My question**: does the mean absolute deviation error
$$
MADE(\hat{\theta})=E(|\hat{\theta}-\theta|)
$$
 have a similar decomposition?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for your reply. Would you say it is a function of bias and variance? From an intuitive point of view, MSE is similar to MADE in terms of what it is measuring.

Comment: No, it's not a function of bias and variance, except perhaps in restricted circumstances (restricting consideration to particular families, for example).

Comment: @Glen_b Would it be fair to say that MAE is a function of bias, variance, and maybe some other terms, depending on the situation?

Comment: That's rather vague. In the broadest possible sense it's trivially true but perhaps not in any clearly useful way. To simplify the discussion, imagine bias is 0. They both relate to the distribution of $\hat\theta$ but you could move MAE and variance together, or either one could go up while the other went down, or one could stay constant while the other changed.

Comment: I would say no, simply because absolute function does not enjoy nice algebraic expansion which meaningfully formulates the expressions inside the bias and variance. By contrast, square function does.

Comment: @Glen_b , do you know any webpage or could you give us a link, where the calculation is shown? Thanks!

Comment: Where what calculation is shown?